# Node js for loop to query mysql does not work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest, for-loop

In node js, after running the for loop, descrip does not contain anything, no field written into the descrip array, why?

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Body parser for fetch posted data
var app = express()
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    host : 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx',
    user : 'admin',
    database :'admin_btb',
    password : 'password'
    });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body parser use JSON data

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
        var token = req.body.token;
        var data = req.body;
        console.log(data);
        var barcode = req.body.barcode;
        var price = {
            "number":0,
            "price":""
            };
             connection.query("SELECT token from device where token = ?",[token],function(err, rows, fields){
                 if(rows.length != 0){
                    console.log("total = "+barcode.length);
                    for( var i = 0,length = barcode.length; i < length; i++){
                        //if (err) throw err;
                        console.log(i);
                        console.log(barcode[i])
                        console.log("Debug 1");
                        connection.query("SELECT unitprice from product where barcode = ?",[barcode[i]],function(err, rows, fields){
                            console.log("Debug 2");
                            price["price"[i]] = rows;
                            console.log("Debug 3");
                            console.log("Debug 4");
                            console.log(rows);
                            //res.json(rows);

                        });

                     console.log("Debug 5");
                     }
                    console.log("Debug 6");
                  }else{
                    res.status(400).send("not have token"); 
                  }console.log("Debug 7");
            }); 
});
```

debug result

```
{ token: '123456789',
  barcode: [ '0123456789', '987654321', '45243453', '987654321' ] }
total = 4
0
0123456789
Debug 1
Debug 5
1
987654321
Debug 1
Debug 5
2
45243453
Debug 1
Debug 5
3
987654321
Debug 1
Debug 5
Debug 6
Debug 7
Debug 2
Debug 3
Debug 4
[ { unitprice: 10 } ]
Debug 2
Debug 3
Debug 4
[]
Debug 2
Debug 3
Debug 4
[ { unitprice: 30 } ]
Debug 2
Debug 3
Debug 4
[ { unitprice: 30 } ]
```

test by Postman
http://i.imgur.com/2etpk5e
I want to query uniprice add to price, but the code doesn't sort it.
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: what descrip, where? `descrip` does not show up ANYWHERE in your code.

Comment: I would recommend you to read a good tutorial on how nodejs works, especially the part of how loops work. Specifically in your case, read how the loop might complete before your sql is called and you end up calling sql with the same values.